# How to load all the urls in the component did mount and onclick should populate the table with state variables specific to the item selected?

Tags: reactjs

Is there any way to load all the url at component did mount and update state variable. Onclick of particular item, state variable specific to that item should be displayed.Or is there any better way to do this ?
Only the contents of the table should be updated onclick.I have api for each of the item in the dropdown. Onclick of particular from the dropdown in tab, state variable should be updated based on selection and displayed in table. Is there any better way to do this ?

```
export class HomeComponent extends React.Component{
  
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      version :[],
      loading : true,
      show : false 
    
    }
    this.showVersion = this.showVersion.bind(this);
  }
  showVersion(vsg_component){
        switch(vsg_component){
          case 'option1':
            var  base_url  = "" 
          case 'option2' :
            var base_url  = "" 
        }
        this.call_function(base_url, version_url)
        this.setState({
          show : true
        })
        return false;
    }

    call_function(base_url, version_url){
      fetch(base_url) 
      .then(response =>{
          return response.json();
      }) 
      .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                  version : data,
                  loading : false
               })
             })
       .catch(error=>{
          console.log(error);
       })
    }
    // componentDidMount(){
    // this.call_function();
   //}



    render(){
    
    const contents = this.state.version.map((h,i)=>{
      return <tr>
        <td>{h.hostName}</td>
        <td>{h.release}</td>
      </tr>
    })

    return(
      <div>
      <div class="header">
        <h1 class="main_header">VSG DASHBOARD</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar">
       <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">VERSION 
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#" onClick ={() => this.showVersion('option1')}>VNF</a>
        <a href="#" onClick ={() => this.showVersion('option2')}>CMTS</a>
        <a href="#">CASSANDRA</a>
        <a href="#">KAFKA</a>
        <a href="#">KINESIS</a>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <input type="text" name="searchbar" placeholder="search.." size="40"></input>
  
  </div>
  { this.state.show ?(
    <div className="version_table_component">
    { this.state.loading || !this.state.version ?
    (  <div class= "loader"> </div>

    ) :(
      <table id="vnf_version" class="center">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>HOST</th>
          <th>VERSIONS</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          {contents}
      </tbody>
      </table>
    )}

  </div>): null }

  </div>     
     ) ;
  }
}
```

Here I am using switch case in click event.call_function() function will receive url  corresponding to the clicked item as the parameter and state variable is set which will be shown in the table. Please refer the screenshot.

[![screenshot][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NF6cO.jpg

Comment: Please provide a more precise and abbreviated example

Comment: @GalAbra my question is not clear ?

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1:**

You can put your URLs in array and loop through, then put response data to state by the key, for example `setState({'CASSANDRA': response.data})`
Then by click you store the `Key: CASSANDRA`, and render the data like `this.state[this.state.currentDataKey]`

Also you need to separate your html by components, then you could wrap for example **Menu** component in **memo** or use PureComponent to prevent unnecessary rerendering. Or `<Table data={this.state[this.state.currentDataKey]}/>`

**Case 2:**
If the response might change and you allways relevant data
You can create an object with keys and urls, like this: const urls = {'CASSANDRA': 'url...'}
then by click you put the Key to argument and make a request like request(urls[key]) and store it to state.tableData.

P.S. Don't forget to separate your code to smaller components